# Why do some commands execute properly only when the file being called is inside the working directory

Tags: gnome, command-line, makefile

I'm unable to successfully make a file when I do the following command

```
make /home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile
```

However an executable is created when I do the following

```
cd /home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile
/home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile 
make
```

Comment: I guess because how is the command going to work if there‘s nothing to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `make` command looks for the `Makefile` in the current directory by default.  For the first command you listed to work, you would need a `Makefile` in the current directory that contained a `/home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile` target.

If you want to run `make` in the context of a different directory (and hence pick up a different `Makefile`), you can use the `-C` option.  For example:

```
make -C /home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile [target]
```

Answer (score 2):

The Makefile contains relative paths, which are relative to your current directory. When you aren't in the directory where the codefiles are, the commands will not find the files needed...

Comment: You can use ''--directory='' to direct make to the right directory:
`make --directory=/home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile`

Answer (score 0):

The argument given to make is not the directory to use but the make-target that shoud be build.

Answer (score 0):

use `make -C /home/me/Desktop/folderWithMakefile`